# How do I authenticate a POST to the Discogs API with PHP / cURL

Tags: php, authentication, curl, oauth, discogs-api

I've successfully used the example here https://gist.github.com/tonefolder/44191a29454f9059c7e6 to authenticate a user and to store the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret. I can then make authenticated GET requests using cURL.

I don't know how to make authenticated POST requests though.

I have tried using the $result['header'] from the signed oauthObject in this way:

```
$discogs_username = "'XXXX'";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discogs WHERE username = $discogs_username;", $link);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $discogs_details = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}


$signatures = array(
    'consumer_key'     => 'MyKey',
    'shared_secret'    => 'MySecret',
  'oauth_token'    => $discogs_details['oauth_token'],
  'oauth_token_secret'    => $discogs_details['oauth_token_secret']
);


$jsonquery = json_encode(array(
        'release_id' => '7608939',
        'price' => '18.00',
        'condition' => 'Mint',
        'sleeve_condition' => 'Mint',
        'status' => 'For Sale'
    )
);


$result = $oauthObject->sign(array(
        'path'      => $scope.'/marketplace/listings',
        'signatures'=> $signatures
    )
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MyDiscogsClient/0.1 +http://me.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $result['signed_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization:' . $result['header'])); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonquery);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I get '[message] => You must authenticate to access this resource.'

I'm not sure if i'm doing the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS part correctly, but I can figure that out once i'm actually able to send an authenticated POST! Sorry if there is also loads more wrong with this - I don't use cURL that often!

Comment: I've asked this question on the Discogs API forum too [link](http://www.discogs.com/forum/thread/703535) but nobody has responded. Am I asking for something really obscure here?

Comment: I see that discogs has well api documentation here: http://www.discogs.com/developers and there under quick start: http://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-quickstart, is present PHP Client API library: https://github.com/ricbra/php-discogs-api , you can try to use it for communicating with them instead creating costume methods

Comment: Thanks but that client only appears to support GET requests rather than POST requests

Comment: You have posted only a part of your code or this is the full code you are using?

Comment: There's not that much extra missing, just creating the signatures array, i'll edit it.

Comment: Are you sure the Authentication header is set correctly? It should be like
`Authorization: Discogs token=abcxyz123456`, you can construct it manually with the authentication token to see if that works.

Comment: $result['header'] contains this: `OAuth oauth_nonce="TXf7B", oauth_timestamp="1453899705", oauth_consumer_key="xxx", oauth_token="xxx", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="xxx"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

After reproducing all your steps and fiddling around a bit, I found the following. As a side node, I presumed that the `$scope` variable just contains the API url, namely `https://api.discogs.com`.

As it turns out, signing the OAuth request does also need to know the proper request method you are going to use. You can find that by `var_dump()`ing the `$result` you are getting from the `sign()` call:

```
array(5) {
/// ... snip ...
    'sbs' =>
  string(269) "GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.discogs.com%2Fmarketplace%2Flistings&oauth_consumer_key%XXXXX%26oauth_nonce%3DMOtWK%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1453937109%26oauth_token%XXXXX%26oauth_version%3D1.0"
}
```

So I digged a bit into the code of the ["OAuthSimple" library](https://github.com/tonefolder/oauthsimple/tree/master/php)  that you are using, and it turns out you can just pass the method under an index called "action".

**Solution**

Based on the findings, you will have to change this:

```
$result = $oauthObject->sign(
    array(
        'path' => $scope . '/marketplace/listings',
        'signatures' => $signatures,
    )
);
```

to this:

```
$result = $oauthObject->sign(
    array(
        'path' => $scope . '/marketplace/listings',
        'signatures' => $signatures,
        'action' => 'POST',
    )
);
```

**Side notes**

I actually tried that solution and was able to create a listing through the API. The only other change I had to make is the condition and sleeve_condition values `Mint` are not allowed by their API so you actually have to use **`Mint (M)`**.

Also, I got an error at first that said I have to complete my "seller settings". So you might want to catch that case in your application.

**Further thoughts**

As you mentioned in the comments to your original post, you presume that the [suggested library](https://github.com/ricbra/php-discogs-api) just allows GET requests also. However, as [you can see here](https://github.com/ricbra/php-discogs-api/blob/master/lib/Discogs/ClientFactory.php#L32), it just returns a [Guzzle Client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), so firing POST requests via this should not be a problem at all, and actually using this would probably save you a lot of pain. I did however not try that, so, just as thought.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks @ArSen - the answer was so simple in the end. Hope this helps other people too!